# Frequently slow interface on Ubuntu 12.10, 12.04, .

Tags: unity, 12.10, desktop-environments

About my system : 
Dual boot Window7/Ubuntu 12.10
RAM : 1 GB
CPU : Intel® Pentium(R) 4 CPU 3.20GHz × 2 
OS type: 32 bit
Disk : 50 GB
Driver : VESA: Intel(r)915G/915GV/910GL Graphics
Experience : Standard

I have been using on this machine since, version 8.04 LTS. But from, 10.04, I have been having problem of slow interface, which happens, most of times, whenever I install updates. But not all update makes interface slow. So sometimes, I enjoy Ubuntu with fast navigation.

Unity, GNOME, Unity 2D, all suffer from this problem. I also tried various kernel versions, but no change.
I have not installed any proprietary drivers myself.

Slow interface : App laoding speeds, maximise minimise and everything else is sluggish and feels unresponsive.

Can some one give me idea, how to diagnose this issue, and resolve it, because it has been pestering since long time.

]This is result of top command (when chrome, gedit, and one terminal was open, but still interface/gui navigation was slow) :
Code:

```
top - 05:05:36 up 19 min,  2 users,  load average: 3.25, 2.72, 1.86
Tasks: 162 total,   1 running, 161 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 47.6 us,  5.5 sy,  0.2 ni, 24.2 id, 22.5 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.1 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   1018804 total,   942812 used,    75992 free,    10404 buffers
KiB Swap:  1951740 total,     2612 used,  1949128 free,   364448 cached


  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND           
 2162 someone   20   0  407m 175m  31m S  81.9 17.6  14:07.98 compiz            
 1592 root      20   0  104m  49m 7348 S  18.9  5.0   1:58.85 Xorg              
 3082 someone   20   0 95752  15m  10m S   6.3  1.5   0:02.26 gnome-terminal    
 3156 someone   20   0  5204 1276  980 R   6.3  0.1   0:00.01 top               
    1 root      20   0  3624 1892 1240 S   0.0  0.2   0:00.99 init              
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd          
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.16 ksoftirqd/0       
    5 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.53 kworker/u:0       
    6 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 migration/0       
    7 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/0        
    8 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/1       
    9 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.10 kworker/1:0       
   10 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.15 ksoftirqd/1       
   11 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/1        
   12 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cpuset            
   13 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khelper           
   14 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdevtmpfs
```